# Obtaining frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe in Python:

```
Value
Apple, Banana, Pineapple 
Apple, Orange, 
Celery, Carrot, Beetroot, Cucumber
Watermelon, Apple, Lychee
```

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': ['Apple, Banana, Pineapple', 'Apple, Orange', 'Celery, Carrot, Beetroot, Cucumber', 'Watermelon, Apple, Lychee']})
```

Each row is a string for value (ex: `Watermelon, Apple, Lychee` is a string) . I have extracted the values into a list:

```
listdf = dataframe["value"].to_list()
```

May I know how could I make a frequency of fruits just as follows?:

```
Apple 3
Banana 1 
Pineapple 1
..
```

I can't use value_counts() to `listdf` as `listdf` is a list.

Comment: is this pandas?

Comment: yes it is a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to split on comma using `str.split`, then create a Series object using `explode`, then use `value_counts` to count frequency:

```
out = df['Value'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
```

Another method is to use the built-in `collections.Counter` method:

```
from collections import Counter
out = pd.Series(Counter([x for s in df['Value'].tolist() for x in s.split(', ')]))
```

Output:

```
Apple         3
Banana        1
Pineapple     1
Orange        1
Celery        1
Carrot        1
Beetroot      1
Cucumber      1
Watermelon    1
Lychee        1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: another way to use Counter: `pd.Series(Counter(df['Value'].str.split(', ').sum()))`